# npm test Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, docker, dockerfile, aws-codebuild

I have a build running on AWS CodeBuild and I get an error:

```js
[Container] 2022/02/17 18:56:05 Running command docker run -e "CI=true" -t $STATIC_IMAGE_TAG ./run_tests.sh
471 /app/run_tests.sh:2
472 npm test
473     ^^^^
474 
475 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
476     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
477     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
478     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
479     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
480     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
481     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
482     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
483 
484 [Container] 2022/02/17 18:56:07 Command did not exit successfully docker run -e "CI=true" -t $STATIC_IMAGE_TAG ./run_tests.sh exit status 1
485 [Container] 2022/02/17 18:56:07 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
486
```

AWS CodeBuild commands that are executed

```js
- docker build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN="${NPM_TOKEN}" --build-arg REACT_APP_POSTHOG_TOKEN="${REACT_APP_POSTHOG_TOKEN}" --cache-from $STATIC_IMAGE_TAG -t $STATIC_IMAGE_TAG . && docker save -o $STATIC_CACHE_PATH $STATIC_IMAGE_TAG
      - docker run -e "CI=true" -t $STATIC_IMAGE_TAG ./run_tests.sh
```

Dockerfile:

```js
FROM node:12

# Grab the NPM_TOKEN variable from the environment
ARG NPM_TOKEN
ARG REACT_APP_POSTHOG_TOKEN

RUN mkdir /app
COPY .npmrc package.json package-lock.json /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install --production
RUN npm install -g license-checker

ENV INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false

COPY . /app
RUN rm -f .npmrc
RUN npm run build

RUN export STATICDIRNAME="$(node -e 'mod=require("./index"); console.log(mod.staticdir);')" && \
    mkdir "/tmp/package" && \
    license-checker --json --out /tmp/package/all_licenses.json && \
    cp -r "$STATICDIRNAME" "/tmp/package/public" && \
    node -e 'mod=require("./index"); delete mod.staticdir; console.log(JSON.stringify(mod, null, 4));' > "/tmp/package/index.json" && \
    echo "tag: \nrevision: $(git rev-parse HEAD)\ntimestamp: $(date +%FT%T%z)" > "/tmp/package/public/release.txt" && \
    tar cvjf "/package.tar.bz2" -C /tmp "package" && \
    rm -rf "/tmp/package"
```

Docker is running node v12.
React project generated with create react app.
When i execute the run_tests.sh script locally it runs fine without any issues.
The tests are also passing locally.
I have no clue why i get this error inside a script.

**Solution**:
run_tests.sh didn't have execution permission. Changing permissions on the file resolved the problem.

Comment: Do you have a `test` script in the scripts section of your package.json file?

Comment: The script is present. I figured out the issue. run_tests.sh script didn't have any execution permission. Running chmod +x run_tests.sh resolved it.